# Which jQuery 2.x.x version is safe to use with jQueryUI 1.12?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, jquery-ui, version

Currently we are using jQuery 1.12.4 & jQueryUI 1.11.4. We are looking to upgrade jQuery to 2.x.x and jQueryUI to 1.12.

I know that jQueryUI 1.12 supports jQuery versions 1.7.0 – 3.1.0 but I would like to know which specific 2.x.x version which would be the best.

https://blog.jqueryui.com/2016/09/jquery-ui-1-12-1/

Comment: Why are you looking to use jQuery v2? It's still old and has some security issues. I'd suggest that if you're going to upgrade, then upgrade to the latest version with all the latest optimisations and security fixes applied to it. At time of writing that's 3.6.0. jQueryUI will still work with this.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I read in some blogs that jquery 3.x.x versions has some issues with jquery ui and in jquery ui 1.12.1 blog I read it supports (1.7.0 – 3.1.0) versions of jquery so I was skeptical. What do you think I should go for if I'm going for jquery 2.x.x version as an alternative?

Comment: I would still use jQuery 3. If you believe that there are issues with jQueryUI holding you back from upgrading other libraries (which is entirely possible as jQueryUI is no longer actively maintained and is effectively an end of life project), I'd suggest rebuilding the UI to remove jQueryUI entirely.

Comment: Thank you! Have a great day ahead.

Comment: Which library would you recommend that is closest to Jquery UI (having similar fancy pop-ups, and fancy image-less radio buttons?: https://jqueryui.com/checkboxradio/#no-icons )

Comment: There's quite a few, such as Bootstrap or Material. I'd suggest doing some research to find ones which best fit your needs.

Comment: Have used jQuery 3.3,1 and jQuery 3.4.1 with jQuery UI with no issues. Please read the blog you posted: "*jQuery UI 1.12 officially supports jQuery 1.7.0 – 3.1.0.*"